# Panal data, simple model averaging in R

Tags: r, model-averaging

For my master thesis I working on model averaging for panel data.
So far I was not able to use common model averaging packages (BMS, BMA) because I use panel data (plm regression first differences).
My first question would be, is it possible to use those packages with panel data?

If not, I managed to construct a restricted (pvalue > .1 and sign restriction for economic data) model space but I don't know how to proceed. Is for example a equal weight average of all models simply to average the different model coefficients?

y = x1 + x2

y = x1 + x2 + x3

How would you average those two models (equal weights)?